# Revision Tracking Graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Define the Revision Tracking Graph (RTG), which is an oriented graph (without circles) where each node x has a set C(x) associated with it, which contains all edges leading into it on all paths from a node 0 (node with empty set). Each edge can be in a set exactly once!

You can also describe this data structure by the rules for its growth:

1. Start with node 0 with associated empty set `C(0) = {}`
2. For any node x create a new node y where (x,y) is oriented edge from x to y and 
   `C(y) = C(x) union { (x,y) }`
3. For any nodes f and t, create node r, where (f,r) and (t,r) are oriented edges and 
   `C(r) = C(f) union C(t) union { (f,r), (t,r) }`

Those rules can be described by words as 1) creating new object 2) branching and versioning 3) merging. You can see that the only difference between branching and versioning is whether there already is an edge leading from a node or not.

You can further differentiate the graph by naming branches (paths in the graph).

Base node is defined as a node b, such as `C(b) = C(f) intersect C(t)`. For short: `Result=(From-Base)+To`. In other words, if you remove all edges in C(b) from C(f) and add edges from C(t), the resulting set would have every edge exactly once and all edges from C(f) and C(t) would be present in C(r).

I have actually several questions pertaining to this data structure:

> 1. Prove there are no circles in the graph
> 2. Prove that for certain graphs there are such nodes F,T for which base cannot be found as specified in simple equation.
> 3. Prove that for each graph and each pair of nodes F and T, there is a set of n pairs of nodes Fi,Bi where Fn = F and `R = T + Sum(i=1..n) of (Fi-Bi)`.
> 4. Create algorithm to find B in simple case where n = 1.
> 5. Create algorithm to find Fi,Bi for i=1..n where n > 1.

I know the answers to 1,2 and 4, but I put them here to get you in the mood of working with this data structure. Have fun with it, pose additional problems and find answers. Any new answers could significantly advance the theory behind revision control systems.

Comment: "Have fun with it" is not really a question... are you posing these questions as a puzzle/research problem?

Comment: Explanation: Edges represent changes, Nodes represent versions and C(x) is a set of all changes contained in version x. (2) Proves 3-way merge is not always sufficient and simple base sometimes cannot be found in complex RTG. Finding base to solve the equation makes possible for 3-way merge tool to merge a change.

Comment: Well, there are 5 questions in there. I'm mainly putting it here so I don't have to repeat all the definition when talking with various mathematician friends and to have a single place for discussing the problem and in hopes someone on this site who I don't know can come up with the answers to questions 3 and 5.

Comment: Definition of base is not clear. What are $f$, $t$ and $r$ there? Are $+$ and $-$ same as set operations union and difference?

Comment: f,t,r are variable names for nodes. F is from version, T is to version and R is for result version (new node). Fixed the definition of the base. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: I think this is off-topic for this site unless you narrow it down to a single focused question that can have a clear-cut answer. [From the FAQ](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask): *If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.* If what you want is "to have a single place for discussing the problem", you should start a blog or post somewhere like Google+.

Comment: There really is one question I need to answer, Rahul. It is the question number 5, but unless I put it all out there, it does not let you in the frame of mind to work with this structure to even get close to answering it. And I think answering question 3 is a way to get there. Question 1,2,4 are just warm up to frame the problem.

Comment: The statements regarding $r$ are still not clear. I can see what you mean by base and why it need not always exist. But I still do not understand what $r$ means. Is it an existing node? Is it given or are you supposed to find it? It helps if you can tell what exactly it is that you want finally, what is the meaning or significance of writing $r$ as in your third question etc.

Comment: Also, you are using $+$ and $-$ for set operations, which I am guessing mean disjoint union and difference operations. You need to write those more clearly and have a look at [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), on how to write math expressions.

Comment: r is a new node you create in the process with edges from f and t pointing to it. The rule 3 is a rule to create node r. (As a result of the merge)

Comment: Please, feel free to help me update the question to make it more readable. I'm new here, this is my first try.

Comment: Are there more conditions on $f_i$ and $b_i$? If not, you could just take $f_1=f$ and $b_1=t$. I am guessing $C(f_i) \supseteq C(b_i)$, is that correct? But, what is the significance of these $f_i$ and $b_i$ (I mean, why this particular way to decompose, does it have any meaning or use)? What is it that you want to find finally? Is it just to find $C(r)$, because that can be found directly as union of $C(f)$ and C(t). Also, there could be multiple $f_i$ and $b_i$ satisfying your condition, what is the criterion to  pick one among them?

Comment: C(r) is easy to find. The problem a series of 3-way merges that would produce the result. I think the part missing is that intersection of each two of C(T), C(Fi)-C(Bi) i=1..n is empty set. Would you help me write this down in a better way?

Comment: It looks like we found a problem with the data model with polkjh, I will edit the question soon to get it fixed.

Comment: Cross-posted to cstheory: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/14991/revision-tracking-graph